# pass json file as command line argument through parser , is this possible?

Tags: python, json

I need to overwrite json file parameters to a python dictionary through command line argument parser. Since, json file is located in the current working directory but its name can be dynamic , so i want something like below :-

> python  python_script  --infile  json_file

## python_script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   profileInfo = dict()
   profileInfo['profile'] = "enterprisemixed"
   profileInfo['nodesPerLan'] = 50
```

## json_file:

```
{
   "profile":"adhoc",               
   "nodesPerLan" : 4
}
```

I tried to add the following lines, but don't know how to load this json data to the python dictionary :-

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--infile', nargs = 1, help="JSON file to be processed",type=argparse.FileType('r'))
arguments = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Well, reading python doc should be enough:
For files : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html
For JSON part : https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html
For args : use a lib

Comment: @fmarc i have tried the above code, i am new to python . I know about json load method but it will load the specific file only , which i don't want in my case thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the JSON file with the name given to `--infile` and update your `profileInfo`:

```
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--infile', nargs=1,
                    help="JSON file to be processed",
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'))
arguments = parser.parse_args()

# Loading a JSON object returns a dict.
d = json.load(arguments.infile[0])

profileInfo = {}
profileInfo['profile'] = "enterprisemixed"
profileInfo['nodesPerLan'] = 50

print(profileInfo)
# Overwrite the profileInfo dict
profileInfo.update(d)
print(profileInfo)
```

Comment: great ! this is exactly what i was looking for gomawoyo ! @Nightcrawler

Comment: Is there a more dynamic solution for this? Say you don't know the filed name in advance. It would be nice if there is a tool that can support parameters in Json files

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you have _nargs=1_ in there. With it, the result gets returned as a list and you have to index it via _infile[0]_, and without it, you can just do _json.load(arguments.infile)_.

Comment: The `jsonargparse` package has a nice solution for this (and much more), see https://jsonargparse.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#configuration-files. IMHO better than rolling our one's own argparse and json merge logic.